# How to pass the values to a reusable component using the @Input annotation?

Tags: angular, input, parent-child

I want to take the user input from app.component and pass these parameters to the ReusableComponent, process that input and display the result. I have a child component in the reusable component known as "mycanvas".

In the parent app.component.html:

```html
<div>
<app-reusable-component [filename]="'assets/base1.STL'" [colorname]="'red'" [perspective]="35">
</app-reusable-component>
</div>

<div class="stl">
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Name of the file</mat-label>
  <mat-hint> File path of only stl file</mat-hint>
  <input  matInput  [(ngModel)]="assets/base1.STL"  name="filename"  required>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Name of the color</mat-label>
  <mat-hint> Color in string</mat-hint>
  <input  matInput  [(ngModel)]="red" name="colorname"  required>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Camera Perspective</mat-label>
    <mat-hint> values in Integer</mat-hint>
    <input  matInput  [(ngModel)]="35" name="perspective"  required>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

In the app.component.ts, I have imported the ReusableComponent:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import {ImlStlAppComponent} from 'src/app/iml-stl-app/iml-stl-app.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  title = 'stl-app';

  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit():void{}
}
```

I want to pass this parameters as user input to the reusable component and accept the components with @Input annotation:

```ts
export class ReusableComponent implements OnInit {


@Input()
filename:string;
@Input()
colorname:any;
@Input()
perspective:number;

function doSomething(){}
}
```

In the ResuableComponent.html I have:

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
<canvas #myCanvas id="myCanvas">
</canvas>
</div>
```

I think I could not able to establish the communication between the reusable component and the app component, so nothing is displayed. Could anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should create your model for inputs. In your component for example:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  filename: string;
  colorname: string;
  perspective: string;
```

Then you can use this variables as models in your input and send to your custom components.

```
<app-reusable-component [filename]="filename" [colorname]="colorname" [perspective]="perspective">
```

And change your inputs:

```
<input  matInput  [(ngModel)]="filename"  name="filename"  required>
<input  matInput  [(ngModel)]="colorname" name="colorname"  required>
<input  matInput  [(ngModel)]="perspective" name="perspective"  required>
```

If you need initial value, you can initialize your model variables with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it from `App.Component` as below.

Define variables in `App.Component`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  title = 'stl-app';
  fileName="file.hgt";
  color="blue";
  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit():void{}
}
```

In `app.component.html` , use `ReusableComponent`  as below

```
<app-resuable-component [filename]="fileName" [colorname]="color">

</app-resuable-component>
```